# Azure mobileServiceClient InvokeApiAsync never returns in my Xamarin iOS app

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I am using the Azure MobilServiceClient to call my custom controller and method and it just never returns. Using the same code in my Test project works just fine, but in my iOS app it just goes silent. Hanging the app.

I call it like this:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "loginProvider", loginProvider }, { "providerKey", providerKey } };
                var result = await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<AuthResult>("Auth", HttpMethod.Get, parameters);
```

I can look in the Azure Log Stream and see that the call is received as expected. Looking the same both from my test project and the App project. No errors.

What else can I try? Where else can I look?

I tried putting the same code piece into the sample code I can download from the Azure portal and it goes silent just like my own app.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the test project? It would be helpful to know how you verified that the API is working at all.

Comment: Well the test project is a clean class project where I added the same Nuget containing MobileServiceClient. And when I make the API call from there it all works fine. The call is returned and the json is deserialized.
Looking at the Azure log stream, I see the same output regardless if I call from my test project or my App project, but in the app project it never returns.

Comment: What NuGet package version are you using?

Comment: Latest versions of the Mobile Service Client related nugets. I actually tried creating a brand new web app in Azure and just ran the quick start code as is. Everything works just fine but not the custom api calls.

I gave up on using the invokeApi methods and rolled my own HttpClient calls which worked on first attempt.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce this in order to identify the issue you hit. Just to confirm, you were using the latest Mobile Service Client (1.3.2), not Mobile Apps, and managed to repro with the quickstart (.NET backend and Xamarin.iOS client) with no modifications except for adding a custom API and calling InvokeApiAsync, correct?

Comment: Using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 2.0.0 or 2.0.1  not sure which comes in the quickstart.

Comment: In Azure I created it by going: New -> Web + Mobile -> Mobile App (orange boxy icon). 
I didn't add or connected to any DB. Didn't add any  Quick APIs either. I tried with and without authentication enabled.
I tried with Google authentication and that part worked just fine but it didn't solve the custom api problem.

Comment: It seems that this is related to any async httpClient calls I make, regardless if I use mobile service client or httpClient directly.
I must be doing something very wrong. Will investigate and return...

Answer (score 1):

Found the source of my problems: async deadlock.

I moved out my async api calls from the PCL app constructor and configured my calls with

```
.ConfigureAwait (false)
```